# Changing local host to custom domain

Tags: url, url-rewriting, localhost, local

So what I am trying in my windows hosts file is:

127.0.0.1:8079   test.mydomain.com

But when I run the local server and hit test.mydomain.com nothing happens. I was expecting that URL to resolve to localhost:8079?

I am running a jetty server.

Comment: hosts file should not contain ports, only ip/name pairs

Comment: What if I have to use a port?

Comment: then just use it in browser's url, like `http://test.mydomain.com:8078/` one hostname can respond on multiple ports

Comment: The port thing was the issue thanks for point that out. Why cant I say you answered it though?